# How to get button's id upon clicking it?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have an html input button element. Upon clicking on it, I want it to invoke a function `hideRoutine`.

What `hideRoutine` is meant to do is hide the div `ExerciseType`. I assumed that upon the invocation, that a reference to that element would be passed which could be referenced within the function.

```
<div className="ExerciseRoutine">
    <input type="button" value="hide" onClick={hideRoutine}/>
    <hr/>
    <div className="ExerciseType">...</div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Is there a way, with JQuery or otherwise, that allows targeting of the element with which the function was invoked? Using it, I'd be able to get the parent div's child representing `ExerciseType`, and hide it thusly.

Comment: This isn't pseudocode. It's React.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the element the React way, you need to use state.

Your onClick handler needs to set the state to tell ExerciseType whether or not to render.

Try something like this:

```js
class Banana extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      showExerciseType: true,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div className="ExerciseRoutine">
          <input type="button" value="hide" onClick={() => { this.setState({ showExerciseType: false }); }}/>
          <hr/>
          {this.state.showExerciseType ? <div className="ExerciseType"></div> : null}
          <br/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make in jquery like this

```
<div class="ExerciseRoutine">
    <input type="button" value="hide" onClick="hideRoutine(this);" />
        <hr/>
        <div class="ExerciseType">...</div>
        <br/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function hideRoutine(event){
        // just in case you need to access the element id
        var elementId = event.id,
        parentElement = event.parentElement.className;
        $('.'+parentElement+'').find('.ExerciseType').hide();
     }
</script>
```